# Using value returned in a function as a parameter in another

Tags: python

Is it possible to do this?

Here's a simple example of what I want to do:

```
def getsize():
    size = input('size?')
    return size

def makebox(getsize()):
    blahblah
```

Comment: `def makebox(): size = getsize(); ...`?

Comment: Ever checked a basic Python tutorial?

Comment: Not to sound condescending, but i would suggest going through a python book or tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, in fact, 2 different stages: definition of function and its call. First goes definition:

```
def getsize():
    size = input('size?')
    return size

def makebox(size):
    # Some code goes here
```

And then you call `makebox()` like this:

```
makebox(getsize())
```

Comment: Doh. Forgot about that. Thanks!